# Faulting module path: C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll

Tags: windows, .net

Есть .NET x86 консольное приложение Executor.exe, которое запускается в Task Scheduler на различных Windows Server 2008 R2.

На одном из серверов в EventLog в Application валиться такая ошибка:

> Faulting application name: Executor.exe, version: 8.0.5711.22101, time stamp: 0x55d6ec7b
>   Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.18933, time stamp: 0x55a69ec4
>   Exception code: 0xe0434352
>   Fault offset: 0x0000c42d
>   Faulting process id: 0xf90
>   Faulting application start time: 0x01d0e014c4d6bbe5
>   Faulting application path: C:\P1\Bin\Executor.exe
>   Faulting module path: C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
>   Report Id: 042d5ce5-4c08-11e5-859f-d8ea27135603

**UPD**

Параметры сообщения:

- Source: .Net Runtime
- Event ID: 1000

Данное сообщение возникает в паре с сообщением:
 - Source: .Net Runtime
 - Event ID: 1026
 - Message:

> Application: Executor.exe
>   Framework Version: v4.0.30319
>   Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>   Exception Info: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException
>   Stack:
>      at System.Diagnostics.ListenerElement.GetRuntimeObject()
>      at System.Diagnostics.ListenerElementsCollection.GetRuntimeObject()
>      at System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.Initialize()
>      at System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.TraceEvent(System.Diagnostics.TraceEventType, Int32, System.String)
>      at Program.Main(System.String[])

Как её победить?

Comment: Положить всё try/catch, при приходе исключения залогировать его и завершить выполнение корректно.

Comment: @VladD Так и сделано. Дело в том, что основной функционал отрабатывает без ошибок, т.е. в catch ничего не поподает.

Comment: Хм, странно. То есть это _не_ выбрасываемое исключение?

Comment: @ValdD Да. Сообщение появляется на каждый старт.

Comment: Ну, если воспроизводится, то можно поэкспериментировать. Пример: воспроизводится ли проблема на простом helloworld?

Comment: Кстати! А вы уверены, что точно ловите все исключения? У вас там нет многопоточности, например? http://stackoverflow.com/a/23293119/276994

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в ошибке в кофиг файле.

Один из source-ов имел ссылку на "Console" listener, который не был объявлен в sharedListeners:

```
<source name="source1" switchName="Switch1">
    <listeners>
       <add name="Console"/>
       <add name="EdgeEventLog"/>
    </listeners>
</source>
```